# How long does the trip in the Hogwarts Express take?

Tags: harry-potter

Firstly, we know the train leaves King's Cross Station at precisely 11 o'clock on the morning of every September 1st and travels to Hogsmeade Station, which is somewhere in Scotland.

We also know from [Scotlandinfo.eu](https://www.scotlandinfo.eu/daylight-hours-sunrise-and-sunset-times/) that in Scotland the sun sets on September 1st at 8:19pm on average. The actual time is either later or earlier depending on where in Scotland Hogsmeade is located. Since September 1st is before the winter equinox (September 22nd or 23rd) the further north we get the later the sunset is going to be (although not by much since we are fairly close to the date of the equinox).

Finally, we know the train arrives in Hogsmeade on September 1st after sunset.

So in conclusion the train ride should be at least 9 hours long, but do we have a better estimate or know the actual time?

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb here and suggest this is one of the things where you've thought about it a lot more than JKR.

Comment: About 9 3⁄4 hours ;)

Comment: It depends a lot on where hogwarts is. Its about 6 and a half hours from king cross to Edinburgh (a number that has pretty steady for the last 100 years so I think we can assume it also applys to the hogwarts express). So then its at least 3 hours from there to anywhere that is sutably remote for hogwarts. If somewhere in the north west highlands, kings cross would still make sense, but you could be talking a 12 hour journey overall.

Comment: They don't have to stop so maybe they could get the london - edinburgh in 4 hours like the dedicated expresses can.

Comment: Calculate 11AM to evening before feast.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We can deduce much from real world trains & routes of similar type:

The [Flying Scotsman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Scotsman_(train)), which was the first express train from London to Edinburgh, ran the trip in over ten hours.

By the late 1800s, the time was down to 8 1/2 hours. By the 1930s, when the [Hogwarts Express locomotive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GWR_4900_Class_5972_Olton_Hall) was built, the time was down to about 7 1/2 hours. Edinburgh is in southern Scotland, and there's still quite a bit of geography to the north.

Sunset at Edinburgh is at 8:07PM and at Inverness, in northern Scotland at 8:14PM on the given day. An approximately nine or ten hour train ride using a 1930s era steam locomotive seems entirely plausible and would get the students to a Highlands location sometime after sunset. Modern trains from London to Inverness take about 12 hours, leaving one to imagine that Hogsmeade is not quite that far north, but also, there are no stops along the way. So they'd reach somewhere between Edinburgh and Inverness at around 9:00PM. Just in time for a feast!

Comment: There's also the obvious potential for magic to speed things along.

Comment: @TylerH It would take a lot of magic. You can't just make the train faster, it would need to fit in with the trains around it. And the east coast mainline is one of the busier lines in the UK.

Comment: Unless the Hogwarts express is engaging in knight bus level magic, in which case it could take anything.

Comment: @user1937198 the train exists at a station platform and on a track that is invisible/separate from what Muggles can see. Platform 9 and 3/4 does not exist in the normal muggle world... it's in its own magical pocket dimension like many other things (Grimmauld Place, Leaky Cauldron, etc.).

Comment: The 19th century history in this post is correct, but to any Brit with memories of the steam era, "Flying Scotsman" of course means the Gresley A1 class locomotive number 1472 (later renumbered 4472). The 7 1/2 hour time in the early 20th century included speed restrictions designed to maintain "fair competition" between the east and west coast line journey times, and there was no technical reason why it could not have been 7 hours from the start of the service hauled by A1 class locomotives, as it became when the restrictions were removed.

Comment: ... The films used a historical engine and carriages from the slower west coast main line service and 42 miles of the west-coast route in Scotland from Fort William to Mallaig, not the faster London-Edinburgh route,.

Comment: @TylerH And for that matter Hogwarts itself, the Ministry, the Quidditch World Cup stadium, and all other "wizarding world" locations.  We muggles have detailed aerial and satellite photography of most of the world.  There's no way we would have missed such prominent locations unless they exist in some alternate dimension we can't detect.

Comment: @TylerH The platform is seperate, but there is no reason to believe its a completely separate line.

Comment: if its completely seperate line, wouldn't it be more convenient and more secure if the platform was in Diagon Alley rather than a major muggle transport hub?

Comment: @user1937198 No, because it's a transportation hub. Magic users may need to travel by mundane means too for a certain leg of their journey. Also, perhaps alternate means of travel, like the Floo network, were not as robust when the train route was created, and it has just been kept for historical reasons. Diagon Alley is a shopping plaza in central London. It's probably very difficult/inconvenient to hide an entire train line there (and *to* there) vs a spot where there are already trains and tracks all the time.

Comment: @user1937198 Also, just a brief bit of sudden head-canon inspiration, but perhaps the platform and Hogwarts Express was not *always* invisible/pocketed away. Perhaps they used more mundane means like forgetfulness charms, etc. (e.g. what they used to deter muggles during construction of the world cup site in the swamp in Goblet of Fire) for anyone who tried to get on, and then with population increases or some technological advancement by muggles, they decided it was time to take more robust measures? It's not really explained beyond "muggles can't see this" as far as I know.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it's explicit said that they have spells on so Muggles can't see them